# EventListener automatically fires up without clicking the button

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I ran into a weird situation(at least to me).  I use jsp to call java code from js.  My goal is that when I click the button, the program should print the *start* in the console, but the program automatically prints out the *start* without waiting me to click the button.  When I change the java code to the typical js code (the commented out one), the program only fires up the event when I click the button.  I don't know why such thing happens.  Hope someone could help me out.  Thank you in advance.

```
<body>
    <button id = "capture">capture</button>
    <script>
        function doCapture() {
            <%
                System.out.println("start");
            %>  
            //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Hello";
        }
        document.getElementById("capture").addEventListener("click", doCapture);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't get it.  All of the code above I wrote is on the server side.  doCapture does not run I click the button, but it automatically runs when the the jsp page is created.  When I changed the system.out.print to document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Hello"; it actually works

Comment: whatever, you are not answering the question.

Comment: that's why I am asking here.  You are welcome to leave me alone then.

Comment: Have it your way - good luck to you and god speed to anyone who tries to help

Comment: why are you mixing server side with client side? It is not the right way to do. You need to do ajax instead.

Comment: @Santhucool thanks. I will take a look at ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with how jsp pages are translated and compiled by the web container. Please go through: 
[this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahe.html)

If you really want to achieve something like this in client side using java, look at:
[java applets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)